# How to convert trained model to Core ML with Tensorflow

Tags: ios, tensorflow

Apple introduces [Core ML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml) this year on iOS11. There's a [Core ML Tool](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/converting_trained_models_to_core_ml) to convert trained model to Core ML format (.mlmodel).

Is it possible to convert Core ML model with Tensorflow? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can train the model through keras.

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('./Any.h5',
                                                input_names='image',
                                                image_input_names='image',
                                                output_names='output',
                                                class_labels=['1', '2'],
                                                image_scale=1/255)
coreml_model.save('abc.mlmodel')
```

.h5 can easily created by 'Sequential'

Answer (score 5):

## [tf-coreml](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml)

You can convert certain common Tensorflow models to CoreML with the [tf-coreml](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml) package.  It is still fairly new as of this writing (Jan 16). It looks to be created by a couple Apple engineers.

## Overview

Based on their examples, you first freeze your TF model using `tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph`, then use the `tfcoreml.convert` method to generate the CoreML object.

## Example

To quote [one of their examples](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml/blob/master/examples/linear_mnist_example.ipynb),

```
"""
Step 1: "Freeze" your tensorflow model - convert your TF model into a 
stand-alone graph definition file
Inputs: 
(1) TensorFlow code
(2) trained weights in a checkpoint file
(3) The output tensors' name you want to use in inference
(4) [Optional] Input tensors' name to TF model
Outputs: 
(1) A frozen TensorFlow GraphDef, with trained weights frozen into it
"""

# Provide these to run freeze_graph:
# Graph definition file, stored as protobuf TEXT
graph_def_file = './model.pbtxt'
# Trained model's checkpoint name
checkpoint_file = './checkpoints/model.ckpt'
# Frozen model's output name
frozen_model_file = './frozen_model.pb'
# Output nodes. If there're multiple output ops, use comma separated string, e.g. "out1,out2".
output_node_names = 'Softmax' 


# Call freeze graph
freeze_graph(input_graph=graph_def_file,
             input_saver="",
             input_binary=False,
             input_checkpoint=checkpoint_file,
             output_node_names=output_node_names,
             restore_op_name="save/restore_all",
             filename_tensor_name="save/Const:0",
             output_graph=frozen_model_file,
             clear_devices=True,
             initializer_nodes="")

"""
Step 2: Call converter
"""

# Provide these inputs in addition to inputs in Step 1
# A dictionary of input tensors' name and shape (with batch)
input_tensor_shapes = {"Placeholder:0":[1,784]} # batch size is 1
# Output CoreML model path
coreml_model_file = './model.mlmodel'
output_tensor_names = ['Softmax:0']


# Call the converter
coreml_model = tfcoreml.convert(
        tf_model_path=frozen_model_file, 
        mlmodel_path=coreml_model_file, 
        input_name_shape_dict=input_tensor_shapes,
        output_feature_names=output_tensor_names)
```

Comment: `For converting TensorFlow models to CoreML format, the recommended approach is to use TensorFlow converter available through new unified conversion API, introduced incoremltools 4.0 python package. ` [source](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml), so use [coremltools](https://github.com/apple/coremltools)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation (for now at least) you'd need to write your own: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/converting_trained_models_to_core_ml#2903105

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, if your machine learning model is in one of the following format:
**Caffe, Keras, XGBoost, Scikit-learn, MXNet,LibSVM**.
There's tutorial and examples for each of them on [Awesome Core ML](https://github.com/likedan/Awesome-CoreML-Models).

Direct conversion from Tensorflow is not yet supported, but you can use Caffe architecture with TF to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. Mostly because there is no format that all NN frameworks should adhere while saving the model.

So probably you will need to rebuild the computation in TF and train your model

Answer (score 0):

[Keras](https://keras.io/) is a high-level neural networks API, written in Python and capable of running on top of [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), CNTK, or Theano.

Currently, [coremltools 0.7](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools) can convert the model of
`Keras (1.2.2, 2.0.4+) with Tensorflow (1.0.x, 1.1.x)`

```
# Make a Keras model
>>> model = Sequential()
>>> model.add(Dense(num_channels, input_dim = input_dim))

# Convert it with default input and output names
>>> import coremltools
>>> coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model)

# Saving the Core ML model to a file.
>>> coreml_model.save('my_model.mlmodel')
```

You can take a look at my project [here](https://github.com/Weijay/DigitRecognition)

Answer (score -1):

Please go to this [link](https://github.com/syshen/YOLO-CoreML/tree/master/Converter)
and see the `Convert_pb_coreml.ipynb`

If you want to convert your trained model i.e ckpt file to pb(Tensor Flow) you can simply use this command In YOLO(Darkflow)

```
./flow --model cfg/(yourCfgFileName).cfg --load -1 --savepb
```

which saves a `.pb` file and a `.meta` file.